# connect users to Custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, users, events

I’ve created a Custom Post Type to manage Events and now, i would like the users of my site (only registered ones) to be able to register to any events created. On the events page, they would just click a button and they would be associated with the event (no need for tickets, payment,…).
I have no clue on where to look at to implement that (taxonomies, meta, … ?) and how this will be stored (on user entity, on event custom post type entity?)
I need help !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save it on user entity. Use update_user_meta() and stock it as an array. In this case if you delete an user, all associates info will be delete too.

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user_events = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_events', true);
$user_events[$event_id] = $event_id; //you can also stock more infos, i use event_id as key to don't have duplicate event by user
update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_events', $user_events);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jerome ! This is helpful. Storing array's in post-meta or user_meta seems to be the right way to do. Now, I have to chose the right one. Your remark regarding deleted users makes sense. I di not think about it.
Now, if I save the event_id arrayin users post_meta, to display the list of users for a specific event, I will have to query users data and find out who is associated with that event_id. Does not sound practical or performant.

The same will happen the other way around if I want to display events connected to a specific user.

Comment: Maybe the solution will be to duplicate the data in both user_meta and post_meta. But duplicating data is something I try at the maximum

Comment: So, you can create a custom database table for relationships. And use add_action( 'delete_user', 'your_function' ) to clean useless data.

Comment: thanks. After thinking the design, this is indeed the approach I will take. Thanks again